# remove default.aspx from a request

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

i am trying to remove default.aspx from any request that might have it.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            string url = context.Request.Url.ToString();

            // remove default.aspx
            if (url.EndsWith("/default.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                url = url.Substring(0, url.Length - 12);
                context.Response.Redirect(url);
            }

        }
```

gives an error:

```
**too many redirects occurred trying to open...**
```

what can i change to make it work?

**thnx**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**k got it.**

instead of using:

```
string url = context.Request.Url.ToString();
```

i tried:

```
string url = context.Request.RawUrl.ToString();
```

**and that WORKS!** together with what you guys said :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you put the redirect inside the if you don't have to deal with infinite redirects.

Answer (score 1):

You are endlessly redirecting.

Each time the following line executes the Application_BeginRequest event is fired again.

```
context.Response.Redirect(url);
```

Put the redirect inside the if statement like this.

```
if (url.EndsWith("/default.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    url = url.Substring(0, url.Length - 12);
    context.Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Comment: probably the default.aspx gets appended since it is listed as default page. how to avoid it??